# How to merge cells using JTable in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Can anyone tell me how do I make table as seen in this image, using Java?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you can use [Swingx Tree Table](http://swingx.java.net/) or implement [your own Tree Table Cell Renderer](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate a bit on the subject? A single phrase with 2 links is kind of a short answer

Comment: You must implement your own Cell Renderer. Think of it as the "panel" that will be shown inside each cell. You can customize the look to your particular needs. Other examples http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: It would nice if you included the important pieces here rather than just posting links. Code sample would be nice.